# Check a key's state without keyPressed/Released events

Tags: java, keyboard, key, keyboard-events, jcreator

I need the check the state of a key (whether it's being pressed down or not) without using an event based method.  Storing key states does not work; I need to check the real time state of the key.  Anybody know how?  Platform is JCreator v5.0 LE

Answer (score 2):

I don't see exactly the point, seeing how `keyPressed()`, `keyReleased()`, and `keyTyped()` are called whenever *any* key is pressed, without fail.

You also said that storing states is not working. Have you tried something like this?

```
boolean[] keys = new boolean[222]; // 222 is the highest keyCode value i know

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true; }
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false; }

// True is pressed, False is released
public boolean getState(int keyCode) {
  return keys[keyCode];
}
```

This is really the most reasonable way of checking the "real-time" state of a key. You can't just ask the computer for the state of a key without using a `Listener`. Perhaps some more information on what you *need* the "real-time" state for will get you a better answer.

Comment: the keyPressed event is being invoked one time after the keyReleased event when I release the key: I press the up arrow, the keyPressed is invoked.  I release the up arrow, the keyReleased is invoked, followed by one keyPressed event.  This is the problem, so I need to check the actual state of the key, not what the KeyListener tells me

Comment: @NathanChan from what I can tell, the code I provided does exactly that. While the key is pressed, `keys[the_key]` will be `true`. When it is not, it will be `false`. Am I missing something?`

Comment: Oh...I see the problem you're having now. I would bet that's a function of your keyboard accidentally sending a key press signal. Even if it isn't accepted by anything, Java will still think a key was pressed.